# Node js server and c++ client socket io connection , not able to emit or read the data

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I cannot get this simple test work. I wrote to the client in C++ and the server in NodeJS, both running on my computer. When I execute the client application, the console outputs this text...but the event 'key' is never fired on the server!

**Client console output:**

```
Error: No active session
[2019-11-21 17:30:11] [connect] Successful connection
[2019-11-21 17:30:11] [connect] WebSocket Connection 127.0.0.1:8081 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.8.1" /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&t=1574353811 101
```

**C++ client**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <sio_client.h>

using namespace sio;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sio::client io;
    io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8081");

    string command = "w";

    io.socket()->emit("key", command );

}
```

**NodeJS server**

```
'use strict';

const express     = require('express');
const app         = express();
const serverHttp  = require('http').Server(app); 
const io = require('socket.io')(serverHttp);

const port = 8081;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {   
    // Never fired :(
    socket.on('key', function (data) {
        console.log("key received!!!");
    });
});

serverHttp.listen(port, function() {  
    console.log("init!!!");    
});
```

### could you please fix this, I saw someone asking the same question in the GitHub issues section for socket io c++ client, no one has answered yet. please help out

Comment: I think they should be connected to the same port ?

Comment: Sorry while editing the question forgot to change the port. its same port.

[2019-11-21 17:30:11] [connect] Successful connection , i am able to get this message in c++ side

Comment: Can you please do a console.log before the comment `// Never fired` and check, if there is a connection or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a brief look through the code it seems that `io.connect` starts a separate thread to do the networking. When it returns the socket is very likely still in a connecting state.
The code for `.emit` ends up [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/src/sio_socket.cpp#L491-L515), which pushes a packet onto the queue and simply returns if the socket is not connected yet.

So I think the root cause of your problem is that the application exits *before the network thread has had a chance to finish connecting*.

The stupidest way to fix this is to simply add a `sleep` statement at the end of your `main` function, to give the network thread a chance to connect and get its message through. A slightly better way is to use `socket.set_open_listener` to get notified when the connection has been opened, and *then* send the message, because that should go through immediately:

```
sio::client io;
io.set_open_listener([&]() {
    io.socket()->emit("key", command);
});
io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8081");
```

This constructs and passes a lambda to `set_open_listener`, where it is stored as a `std::function<void(void)>` internally.

Comment: I was able to send data using sleep.
could you just guide me on how to write an open listener? I'm learning CPP.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hi @botje, it worked with the way u wrote the listener. Thanks a lot.
Could you help me out with the second part of the question, I put a second part for the question please have a look at it.
im a user with less stars i couldnt upvote ur answer cause of that :(

Comment: Ask a new question instead of polluting this one. Also, as the author you should mark answers as accepted instead of upvoting them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178725/set-open-listener-how-to-close-it-in-socket-io-cpp @Botje can u please check this out.