# socket emit inside set_open_listener doesnt work when clear_con_listener is called

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, socket.io

This small portion of the code is inside a function, and this function is being looped around. While running it , it's emitting the data to the server once but after that, it doesn't go inside open listener to emit variable **command**

```
sio::client io;
io.set_open_listener([&]() {
    io.socket()->emit("key", command);
    io.clear_con_listeners();

});
io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8081");
```

I am not able to emit the data 1st, how to make the listener emit first and then close it. Is there a way to do this like async-await in javascript.

Comment: Does "this function is being looped around" mean that the `io` variable is being destroyed? That will kill the connection and any ongoing communication.

Comment: Furthermore: it is unclear from your question if you want *one* invocation at any given moment or have several connections in parallel. Also, why is "this function being looped"? Wouldn't it be better to keep the connection open and `emit` keys as they occur?